# How to get all html elements with id equal to `constant_text-something_changed`?

Tags: python, html, parsing, python-2.7, lxml

I am trying to parse html with lxml like below:

```
<tr id="element-36a07b7" class=" " ... data-date="2014-05-25">
    <td>2014-05-25</td>
    <td>Wikipedia (<a href="http://example.com/36a07b7" title="Wikipedia search">link</a>)</td>
    <td>Yandex (<a href="http://ya.ru/36a07b7" title="Yandex search">link</a>)</td>
    <td title="what I am looking for">another needed info<span class="small">(<a href="http://example.com">info 3</a>)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="result">1</td>
    <td class="result">2</td>
    <td class="result">3</td>
    ...
</tr>
```

and would like to get all elements with id equal to `element-...` and extract `36a07b7`, `data-date`, `what I am looking for`, `another needed info` and `info 3` from there.

Firstly, I am trying to get all `element-`s:

```
elements = t.find('//*[@id="flight-"]')
```

how can use wildcards in the id name? Tried to use `*`, `.*`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `starts-with` function:

```
import lxml.html

root = lxml.html.fromstring('''
<table>
<tr id="element-36a07b7" class=" "  data-date="2014-05-25">
    <td>2014-05-25</td>
    <td>Wikipedia (<a href="http://example.com/36a07b7" title="Wikipedia search">link</a>)</td>
    <td>Yandex (<a href="http://ya.ru/36a07b7" title="Yandex search">link</a>)</td>
    <td title="what I am looking for">another needed info<span class="small">(<a href="http://example.com">info 3</a>)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="result">1</td>
    <td class="result">2</td>
    <td class="result">3</td>
    ...
</tr>
</table>
''')

tr_list = root.xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "element-")]')
for tr in tr_list:
    print tr.get('id').split('-')[1]
    print tr.get('data-date')
```

output:

```
36a07b7
2014-05-25
```

---

Alternatively, you can use css selector, using `cssselect` method:

```
tr_list = root.cssselect('[id^=element-]')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, falsetru! How can I get sub-elements of `tr`? Let's say if I need to get 4th `td` element?

Comment: @LA_, XPath: `//*[starts-with(@id, "element-")]/td[4]`

Comment: @LA_, CSS Selector: `[id^=element-]>td:nth-child(4)`

Comment: Thanks, falsetru. I want to understand how to do it in the cycle, something like like `for tr in tr_list: print tr.get('/td[4]')`.

Comment: @LA_, `print tr.find('td[4]')` or `print tr.find('./td[4]')`

Comment: @LA_, If you want to get text only: `print tr.find('td[4]').text` or `    print tr.find('td[4]').text_content()`